# A weird bug of scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs

Tags: python, scipy

I want to minimize the following function:

[image]

The derivative is obviously:

[image]

Given following code

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
def loss(theta):
    return np.sum(np.abs(theta))

def grad(theta):
    return np.sign(theta)

theta = np.ones(6)
print(scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(loss, theta, fprime = grad ,maxiter= 10000))
```

Obviously the minimum should return [0,0,0,0,0,0]. However the Output is very weird:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

and there is a warning:

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 6.000000
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 48
         Gradient evaluations: 42
```

**How is it possible?**

I use the following code to trick the change of internal theta:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
def loss(theta):
    print(theta)
    return np.sum(np.abs(theta))

def grad(theta):
    return np.sign(theta)

theta = np.ones(6)
print(scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(loss, theta, fprime = grad ,maxiter= 10000))
```

The internal theta is really close to [0,0,0,0,0,0](i.e. [-2.28862373e-07 -2.28862373e-07 -2.28862373e-07 -2.28862373e-07
-2.28862373e-07 -2.28862373e-07]) **but still return [1,1,1,1,1,1] Why?**

PS :

1. The API of **scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs** is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html
2. my version of scipy is 1.3.1

Comment: I am getting the same theta of `[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]` in both functions. I think that in the second function you are printing the values out and interpreting those values as the minimum. If you scroll to the very bottom the array of both function contain `[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]`

Comment: @ThomasHayes Yes, it means that internal theta is close to 0, but still return 1. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the derivative is "obviously" sign(theta), but... it's not. Your function is non-differentiable when any of the coordinates are 0. BFGS relies on the objective function being continuously differentiable, and the update logic doesn't handle the discontinuities well.